# Android Studio Dolphin (2021.3.1.17) won't start, no errors, on Mac (Intel, Monterey)

Tags: android-studio

I was previously running an old 4.0.0 install. Now replacing with the latest stable Android Studio Dolphin (seems to be 2021.3.1.17), on a 2015 Macbook Pro running latest Monterey, and it will not start. Nothing happens at all. Trying to run from Terminal ("open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app") returns no errors, no output. On first run, MacOS does its verification process, and after confirming I want to run a downloaded file, nothing.

Tried:

I've tried removing all traces in ~/Library/Preferences/..., ~/Library/Caches/..., ~/Library/Application Support/..., ~/Library/Logs/... of previous versions. And removed and installed older stable releases, all the way back to 4.2.2 when it worked. But 4.2.2 is too old for the latest codebase.

Is this hardware related... is there a system requirement that might affect this? (info on the Mac is below) I can't see anything in requirements that should case this. Does anyone know of something else I can try, or check?

This is not my screen capture, but demonstrates the same problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg1uP.jpg

About the Macbook Pro:

It's a 2015 Macbook Pro, so Intel based, and **I am definitely downloading the "Mac with Intel chip" version**. It's "2.7 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5" and 8GB of RAM. I know this isn't new hardware, but I can't see a system requirement that should be a problem.

Additional:

After first having this problem, already Monterey, just one recent update behind, I installed the latest Monterey patch. Following the OS reboot and trying Android Studio again, the splash screen actually did appear, and offered to use the old version's prefs, which I did, but the IDE never opened. Now, even after reboots, and several attempts at installing different versions, nothing.